# How to make such a structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What type of structure is this, and how to I make such using a loop?

```
var movies = [
     { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
     { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
     { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];
```

I am using `each` for the loop

```
$.each(result, function(key, value){

    movies??? = this.name;
    movies??? = this.year;

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an array of objects:

```
var movies = [];

$.each(result, function(key, value){
   movies.push({Name: this.name, ReleaseYear: this.year});
});
```

You can see that the wrapping structure is an array:

```
$.isArray(movies); // true
```

And that each element is an object:

```
$.isPlainObject(movies[0]); // true
```

Comment: @Raynos : What can that be used for?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting map takes an array and returns a new one. Rather then interating over the result and adding each one to movie you could map the results array into a new array called movies.

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of <strike>JSON</strike> objects. To add a "movie", just do:

```
movies.push({Name: "Kung Fu Panda 2", ReleaseYear: "2011"});
```

Comment: Something you might find interesting:  This is **NOT** "JSON".  JSON is only JSON when it's a string.  This is an array of JavaScript objects.  There's no such thing as a "JSON object": http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Chris oh, true. I knew there was something i was forgetting.

Comment: What Chris said!  I hear he is a gentleman and a scholar.  The fact that he said the exact thing I did at nearly the same moment is nothing but coincidence!

Comment: Ha! And now I've gone and deleted mine... :)

Comment: @Chris lol! thanks, btw, for explaining that and not immediately downvoting; lol.

Answer (score 2):

```
var movies = [];
$.each(result, function(key, value){
    movies.push( { Name: this.name, ReleaseYear: this.year });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's some movies array object in you loop you can populate it with the name year objects like this:

```
movies.push({Name: "name", ReleaseYear: "2011"});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var movies = $.map(results, function(v) {
  return { Name: v.name, ReleaseYear: v.year };
});
```

[$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Answer (score 1):

@davin covered the implementation, but though I'd cover the initial question.

The object you're looking to create is the object literal notation of javascript.

<strike>More commonly you'll see this same syntax used when transferring information between JS and other technologies (though it can be used in technologies other than JS since it is a standard). In these instances (when serialized) the information is considered to be in [JSON (Javascript Object Notation)](http://www.json.org/js.html) <sup>[[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json)] [[RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)]</sup></strike>

Comment: Object literals are not JSON.

Comment: `object literal !== JSON` !!! And you can use JSON to transfer data between any technology. You have to see JSON as independent format, like XML. I'm starting to think Crockford should have chosen another name... :-/

Comment: @BradChristie your still calling it JSON ;)

Comment: @BradChristie you also need to mention JSON is data, so it's just a string, not a language construct. In reality though JSON and Object literals have nothing to do with each other. It's just become common place to refer to Object literals as JSON because no-one is educated.

Comment: @FelixKling I personally see it as being a JS technology, though you are right. If I was going to transfer something that didn't involve JS, I don't believe I would instinctively (or willingly) select JSON as the medium.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of objects. An array is like a list, so this would be a list of objects. Each object has two properties: Name and ReleaseYear. I'm not sure where your data is coming from, but try something like this:

```
var movies = new Array();
$.each(result, function(key, value){
    movies.push({Name: this.name, ReleaseYear:this.year})        
});
```